# ClassCastException on custom class loading from jar

Tags: java, maven, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I'm trying to implement custom class loader for educational purposes.

I have the module "Weather" in `jar` file which I want load from `App` class by `JarClassLoader`.

Classloader from [here](http://samolisov.blogspot.com.by/2008/01/java.html)  (it loads all classes from the specified jar):

```
package com.example.classloading;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

public class JarClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private HashMap<String, Class<?>> cache = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    private String jarFileName;
    private String packageName;
    private static String WARNING = "Warning : No jar file found. Packet unmarshalling won't be possible. Please verify your classpath";

    public JarClassLoader(String jarFileName, String packageName) {
        this.jarFileName = jarFileName;
        this.packageName = packageName;

        cacheClasses();
    }

    private void cacheClasses() {
        try {
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jarFileName);
            Enumeration entries = jarFile.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry jarEntry = (JarEntry) entries.nextElement();
                // simple class validation based on package name
                if (match(normalize(jarEntry.getName()), packageName)) {
                    byte[] classData = loadClassData(jarFile, jarEntry);
                    if (classData != null) {
                        Class<?> clazz = defineClass(stripClassName(normalize(jarEntry.getName())), classData, 0, classData.length);
                        cache.put(clazz.getName(), clazz);
                        System.out.println("== class " + clazz.getName() + " loaded in cache");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException IOE) {
            System.out.println(WARNING);
        }
    }

    public synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> result = cache.get(name);
        if (result == null)
            result = cache.get(packageName + "." + name);
        if (result == null)
            result = super.findSystemClass(name);    
        System.out.println("== loadClass(" + name + ")");    
        return result;
    }

    private String stripClassName(String className) {
        return className.substring(0, className.length() - 6);
    }

    private String normalize(String className) {
        return className.replace('/', '.');
    }

    private boolean match(String className, String packageName) {
        return className.startsWith(packageName) && className.endsWith(".class");
    }

    private byte[] loadClassData(JarFile jarFile, JarEntry jarEntry) throws IOException {
        long size = jarEntry.getSize();
        if (size == -1 || size == 0)
            return null;

        byte[] data = new byte[(int)size];
        InputStream in = jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);
        in.read(data);

        return data;
    }
}
```

Interface and implementation (just template without any specific logic):

```
package com.example.classloading;   

public interface Module {
    public void demo(String str);
}    


package com.example.classloading;   

public class Weather implements Module {
    public void demo(String str) {
        System.out.println("hello from weather module");
    }
}
```

App class:

```
import com.example.classloading.JarClassLoader;
import com.example.classloading.Module;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JarClassLoader jarClassLoader = new JarClassLoader("classloading/weather-module/target/weather-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", "com.example.classloading");
        try {
            Class<?> clas = jarClassLoader.loadClass("com.example.classloading.Weather");
            Module sample = (Module) clas.newInstance();
            sample.demo("1");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Problem: When I run the main method I get the following output:**

```
== loadClass(java.lang.Object)
== class com.example.classloading.Module loaded in cache
== class com.example.classloading.Weather loaded in cache
== loadClass(com.example.classloading.Weather)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.classloading.Weather cannot be cast to com.example.classloading.Module
    at App.main(App.java:12)
```

Is there a problem in a logic or syntax? `Module` doesn't loaded by application class loader?

---

File tree (slightly simplified) :

```
├───classloading
│   │   pom.xml
│   │
│   ├───menu-module
│   │   │   pom.xml
│   │   │
│   │   ├───src
│   │   │   ├───main
│   │   │   │   ├───java
│   │   │   │   │   │   App.java
│   │   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │   └───com
│   │   │   │   │       └───example
│   │   │   │   │           └───classloading
│   │   │   │   │                   JarClassLoader.java
│   │   │   │   │                   Module.java
│   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   └───resources
│   │   │   └───test
│   │   │       └───java
│   │   └───target
│   │       ├───classes
│   │       │   │   App.class
│   │       │   │
│   │       │   └───com
│   │       │       └───example
│   │       │           └───classloading
│   │       │                   JarClassLoader.class
│   │       │                   Module.class
│   │       │
│   │       └───generated-sources
│   │           └───annotations
│   └───weather-module
│       │   pom.xml
│       │   
│       ├───src
│       │   ├───main
│       │   │   ├───java
│       │   │   │   └───com
│       │   │   │       └───example
│       │   │   │           └───classloading
│       │   │   │                   Module.java
│       │   │   │                   Weather.java
│       │   │   │
│       │   │   └───resources
│       │   └───test
│       │       └───java
│       └───target
│           │   weather-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│           │
│           ├───classes
│           │   │   Module.class
│           │   │   Weather.class
│           │   │
│           │   └───com
│           │       └───example
│           │           └───classloading
│           │                   Module.class
│           │                   Weather.class
│           │
│           ├───maven-archiver
│           │       pom.properties
│           │
│           └───maven-status
│               └───maven-compiler-plugin
│                   ├───compile
│                   │   └───default-compile
│                   │           createdFiles.lst
│                   │           inputFiles.lst
│                   │
│                   └───testCompile
│                       └───default-testCompile
│                               inputFiles.lst
│
└───
```

**Update**: 
I made the change in `JarClassLoader` `cacheClasses()`

```
if (match(normalize(jarEntry.getName()), packageName))
```

to

```
if (match(normalize(jarEntry.getName()), packageName) 
&& !normalize(jarEntry.getName()).contains("Module"))
```

It is workaround. How to do it in a right way?

**Update**: as I understand it is possible to delete `Module` interface from module `Weather` then "declare the "menu" module as a dependency for the weather module" [@Costi Ciudatu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265983/classcastexception-on-custom-class-loading-from-jar#comment73603454_43266189).

Now I have following `pom.xml` files:

**menu-module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>classloading</artifactId>
        <groupId>java-tasks</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>menu</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**weather-module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>java-tasks</groupId>
    <artifactId>weather-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>java-tasks</groupId>
            <artifactId>menu</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**classloading**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>java-tasks</groupId>
    <artifactId>classloading</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>weather-module</module>
        <module>menu-module</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**Problem: I tried to package `weather-module` and got error:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building weather-module 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for java-tasks:menu:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.471 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-07T09:15:38+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project weather-module: Could not resolve dependencies for project java-tasks:weather-module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact java-tasks:menu:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

**How I should configure maven `pom.xml` files for correct working?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your weather module should not contain a copy of the `Module` class.
Otherwise, you end up with two copies of that class, which is the root cause of the `ClassCastException`.

Make the weather module depend on the menu module or extract the `Module` class in a separate one. Bottomline, you should make sure you end up with a single version of `Module` in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you and others for answers. "Make the weather module depend on the menu module" how to do it? (I use IntelliJ idea)

Comment: You seem to be using maven. So all you need to do is declare the "menu" module as a `dependency` for the weather module.

Comment: Could you see the latest update? :) I tried to apply your advices.

Comment: Once you've done that, remove the `Modul.java` file from the weather module.

Comment: I have done that. Doesn't​ work. I suppose there are problem with pom.xml files...

Comment: Try running `mvn package` in the classloading directory. This way, you build both modules at once. Otherwise, you would need to first `install` the menu module for it to be available for the weather module later on.

Answer (score 2):

The class `Module` is loaded by your main classloader of the `App` class. The `Weather` class is loaded by the `JarClassLoader`. By doing this the parent class `Module` is also (again) loaded by the `JarClassLoader` because the parent classloder is not used. So you end up in two similar **but not equal** class instances `Module`. As each class has a reference to its classloader they are different and therefore not compatible.

The main problem is you load all classes even those loaded by another classloader before. Try to cache only the classData in `cacheClasses()` and call defineClass() only if there is no `findLoadedClass()` in the parent classloader.

But this will not help completely as you have completly doubled dependencies in your classloaders. The behaviour will depend on the order the classes are loaded. To make this work you have to split your weather module.

Comment: Thanks. How to "To make this work you have to split your weather module"? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with loading a duplicate class (or interface, in this case) from a JAR file. The Module classes are not compatible, being loaded from two different locations. In general, you shouldn't mix manually loading classes and `import`ing/automatically loading them within a single package.

Comment: Thanks. How can I exclude `Module` interface from weather-module? What is right maven configuration for that?