# Unable to cast to interface class with URLClassLoader and reflection

Tags: java

I have a jar:

`/home/cole/lib/a.jar`

And in this jar I have the following interface/classes (horrible names for illustration purposes only!):

- `CreatorInterface.java`
- `Base.java (implements CreatorInterface.java)`
- `AbstractBase.java (extends Base.java)`
- `Implementation.java (extends AbstractBase.java)`

In a separate project I have the following code:

```
final URL[] jars = new URL[] {
  new File("/home/cole/lib/a.jar").toURL();
}

final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(jars, null);
final Class<?> implementation = classLoader.loadClass("Implementation");
final CreatorInterface object = (CreatorInterface)implementation.newInstance();
```

However when I run the above, I get the following:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: Implementation cannot be cast to CreatorInterface`

Given `Implementation` is ultimately an instance of a class that implements `CreatorInterface`, why do I get the `ClassCastException`?

**Update 1**

This isn't a question about using `URLClassLoader`, the class is found ok, the problem appears to be in the instantiation.  For example, the following code works fine:

```
final Object object = implementation.newInstance();
```

**Update 2**

As @davidxxx answered, I have the interface class twice (once in the jar and once in the project using it).  Although the interface was the same, this was the cause of the issue.

However to make it work, I needed to fix my URLClassLoader like this, to avoid a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
final ClassLoader parent = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(jars, parent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load Classes at runtime from a folder or JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar)

Comment: Updated question, don't think so.  The class is found fine, I can instantiate it fine, I just can't cast it.

Comment: Why is your jar including the interface if it is shared across mutlipe projects? How does your separate project know of the Interface when it is actually located in the jar? Next, loading the same class with two different peer class loaders will result in two different classes actually which can't be casted back and forth, this is probably what you are seeing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassCastException on custom class loading from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265983/classcastexception-on-custom-class-loading-from-jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Implementation cannot be cast to
>   CreatorInterface

makes me think that you have very probably two distinct `CreatorInterface` classes : one included in the jar and another other coming from the client program that tries to load it.
Even if the two classes have the same name (qualified names), these are different classes for each classloader as here you use two unassociated classloaders.
You have the current classloader of the program that you run and this other classloader as you specified `null` as parent classloader :

```
final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(jars, null);
```

So as you try to assign the object created by reflection to the `CreatorInterface` variable, the cast fails because two distinct `CreatorInterface` were loaded by each classloader and are used : one coming from the classloader of your client code and another coming from the the instantiated classloader.
Using a single classloader would solve the issue but a best practice would be including the jar in the classpath of the project and to ensure to  have a single version of the classes provided in the jar.

To decouple things you should probably split the jar into 2 jars : an API jar that contains only the interface and an implementation jar that depends on the API jar and that contains other classes.
In the client code, add in the classpath only the API jar to be able to assign to a variable with the interface declared type.

---

About your second point :

> *This isn't a question about using URLClassLoader, the class is found ok, the problem appears to be in the instantiation. For example, the
>   following code works fine:*

```
final Object object = implementation.newInstance();
```

In this case you don't refer the interface type.
You indeed assign the `Implementation` object to an `Object` and not to  a `CreatorInterface` variable.
The correct/consistent interfaces and subclasses are loaded by the classloader but here you never give a chance to provoke a `ClassCastException` as you never assign it to a type of a duplicate class but `Object` that is defined a single time.
So the problem previously encountered cannot occur.

---

About the third point :

> *However to make it work, I needed to fix my URLClassLoader like this,
>   to avoid a ClassNotFoundException:*

```
final ClassLoader parent = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(jars, parent);
```

It works because here you create a classloader associated to the parent classloader.

In fact if you did :

```
final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(jars);
```

It would produce the same result as the `URLClassLoader` object created would use by default the delegation to the parent classloader (here the classloader that started your application).

Comment: Thanks!  You were absolutely right, but I also spotted another issue in my code.  Updated original answer to reflect this.

Comment: @imrichardcole  Interesting point. I missed something. I updated to be more accurate.